# Crons are running but email not sent out

Tags: php, email, cron

I am running a PHP/MySQL server and am using cron jobs to periodically update my customers as well as send automated newsletters, invoices, etc. However, it does not appear to be working, as emails are not getting sent.

1. The cron jobs are running (checked the logs).
2. Invoking the script via the browser results in the emails being sent.
3. Using SSMTP for email transport.
4. SPF and DKIM records are in place and correct.

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Here is pseudocode of the email script:

```
$override_authentication = true;
require_once('../services/shared/connect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `organizations`";
$orgs = mysqli_query($database,$query);
while ($org = mysqli_fetch_array($orgs)) {

  // GENERATE EMAIL CONTENT HERE

  // Send email to all users
  $query = "SELECT `id`, `email`, `avatar`, `gender`, `phone`, `option_textalerts` FROM `users` WHERE `organization` = " . $org['id'] . " AND `option_scheduling` = 'enabled'";
  $users = mysqli_query($database, $query);
  while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
    $message = emailGetHeader("Submit Availability for ".date('F Y', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')+1,1,date('Y'))), $user) . $body . emailGetFooter();
    $to = $user['email'];
    mail($to,"Submit Availability for ".date('F Y', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')+1,1,date('Y'))),$message,emailGetMeta('Leadsheet <email@leadsheet.us>', 'Leadsheet Automailer <no-reply@leadsheet.us>'));

    // If enabled, sent a text alert to the phone number on their account
    if ($user['option_textalerts'] == 'availability') {
      $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $user['phone']);
      $domains = array('txt.att.net', 'myboostmobile.com', 'sms.mycricket.com', 'tmomail.net', 'vtext.com');
      foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        mail($phone.'@'.$domain, "Availability Reminder",'Please submit your availability for '.date('F Y', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')+1,1,date('Y'))).' on Leadsheet', emailGetMeta('Leadsheet <txt@leadsheet.us>', 'Leadsheet Automailer <no-reply@leadsheet.us>'));
      }
    }
  }
}

mysqli_close($database);
```

Comment: Are you sure your emails are actually getting sent? try `if( !mail(...) ) { // log error } else { // was successful }`. Are you also sure your cron is running properly with the set intervals? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: does the cron itself email you with the output of the script? does the cron user have permissions >= the website user?

Comment: There's not really anything in PHP's built-in mail function that will help you to debug effectively. Best you can hope for is to look at the logs of the mail server. I'd strongly recommend always using a library that will provide you with useful error messages, for example PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They also make sending email a lot simpler.

Comment: The cron is running properly, as the logs show the crons are running. The crontab is not emailing me output, which is suspicious. I have considered implementing a library and will likely do so soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting a friend, I discovered the answer. The cron engine was executing the script from the root directory, so the relative file name in the `require_once` wasn't resolving. Adding a `cd` command before executing the script solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing an environment variable.  look at phpinfo() and compare with your local environment.  Alternatively you can just use [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) to emulate a browser loading the page.